# linear algebra (matrices) - challenging problem (determination of method/algorithm)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, contest-math

I wonder about the following method/algortithm about square matrices $A_{n \times n}$ $\in$ $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{K})$, where $\mathbb{K} $ $\in$ {$ \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ }.

*Given certain value of determinant, propose method of constructing square matrix of any possible dimension with as least 0's as matrix's terms as possible.*

In other words, let me give example:

I have determinant, let say, equal to 5. In what way could I construct matrix of arbitrary dimension (e.g. of dimension 6 x 6)?

To sum up, I wonder about method/algorithm, which enables to construct any square matrix associated with given determinant such that this matrix has as least 0's terms as possible.

By method/algorithm, I mean deterministic procedure, not a guess.

Any help very appreciated!

Comment: There is always a solution where EVERY entry is nonzero, so that the least number of zeroes is $0$.

Comment: Yes, true. But I mean, how to construct possible method generating e.g square matrix of dimension 8X8 given its determinant equals pi?

Comment: I do not mean any rigorous proof here,  but rather efficient method consistent with constraints stated above.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq j}$ where $$a_{ij}=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}1 &\text{if} & i\neq j & \text{or} & i=j=1\\2 &\text{if} & 1<i= j<n,  \\ x+1 &\text{if} & i= j=n,  \\\end{array}\right.$$

Then you can check that the determinant of $A$ is exactly $x$. For example, when $n=5$, $A$ is

$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & x+1 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

As noted by user1551, when $x=-1$ we have the problem that $x+1$ becomes zero ; in this case, simply take the matrix for $x=1$ and interchange any two columns or rows in it.

Comment: Nice example. You may also want to mention that when $x=-1$, the matrix $B$ obtained by interchanging the first two rows of $A(-x)$ is entrywise nonzero and $\det(B)=-1$.

Comment: @user1551 Done, thanks

Comment: @user1551 Is $x+1=0$ a problem? You just do row reduction and it's fine no?

Comment: The matrix $A$ after row reduction becomes
$$
A'=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: @snulty The OP wants the matrix to have as few zero entries as possible. When $x+1=0$, you get a zero entry.

Comment: @user1551 I actually forgot that part, yes I see. Thanks! I thought it was something problematic with the determinant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something similar to Ewan's except it may be more transparent for some.

Firstly if you want $\det=0$ take the matrix of all $1$'s, except of course in the $1\times1$ case.

Then for $\det\neq 0$ take the diagonal matrix 
$D=(d_{ij})_{1\leq i,\,j\leq n}$ where $$d_{ij}=\begin{cases}
 0 &\text{if} & i\neq j \\
 1 &\text{if} & i=j \text{ and } i\neq n  \\ 
x &\text{if} & i=n,  \\\end{cases}$$

so then D pretty much looks like this:

$$
D=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 
1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

It is clear then that $\det(D)=x$. Now adding and subtracting rows doesn't change the determinant so first, add every row (barring itself) to the $1^{st}$ row to give:

$$
D'=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 
1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & x  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x \\
\end{array}\right)
$$
Then finally add the first row to every other row;

$$
D''=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 
1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & x  \\
1 & 2 & 1 & \ldots & x \\
1 & 1 & 2 & \ldots & x \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2x \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

So $\det(D'')=x$, and since this is for $x\neq 0$ none of the entries are zero either.